# Different type error in elasticserach replica mapper

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting

```
 mapper [countCalls] of different type, current_type [long], merged_type [text]
```

It is happening around midnight and the error shows it's a replica problem TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference. There are no settings for mapping this field and I don't have any default mapping. The field is array ["name": value].

Any idea why? I don't have any other errors and I see the events in Kibana with no problems.

Here is whole log:

```
 [2019-11-11T00:02:51,566][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [xxx] [logstash-2019.11.10][0] 
failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[logstash-2019.11.10][_doc][pWKOV24BqMTbC P5UQ9uc], 
 source[{xxxxxxxx, "countCalls":[["i",0]]}]} java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [countCalls] 
 of different type, current_type [long], merged_type [text] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.doMerge(FieldMapper.java:330) ~[elasticsearch-        
 7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.NumberFieldMapper.doMerge(NumberFieldMapper.java:1081) ~     
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.merge(FieldMapper.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-         
 7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.merge(FieldMapper.java:52) ~ 
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.createDynamicUpdate(DocumentParser.java:223) ~     
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:83) ~     
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:267) ~[elasticsearch 
 7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:770) ~ 
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperation(IndexShard.java:747) ~[elasticsearch-     
 7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at 
 org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperationOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:719) ~     
 [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.lambda$executeIndexRequestOnPrimary$3(TransportShardBulkAction.java:452) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeOnPrimaryWhileHandlingMappingUpdates(TransportShardBulkAction.java:475) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:450) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeBulkItemRequest(TransportShardBulkAction.java:218) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:153) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:141) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:79) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:1042) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:1020) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation.execute(ReplicationOperation.java:104) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.runWithPrimaryShardReference(TransportReplicationAction.java:422) [elasticsearch-7.1.1. jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.lambda$doRun$0(TransportReplicationAction.java:363) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:61) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.lambda$wrapPrimaryOperationPermitListener$14(IndexShard.java:2538) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:61) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationPermits.acquire(IndexShardOperationPermits.java:269) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationPermits.acquire(IndexShardOperationPermits.java:236) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquirePrimaryOperationPermit(IndexShard.java:2513) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.acquirePrimaryOperationPermit(TransportReplicationAction.java:979) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:359) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:314) [elasticsearch-7.1.1 .jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:306) [elasticsearch-7.1.1 .jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:251) [x-pack-security-7 .1.1.jar:7.1.1] at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
```

Comment: Once the field is indexed it will be automatically added to you mappings. pull your mappings via kibana and you will see it with long type.

Answer (score 1):

When a new field not declared in mapping or template is found elasticsearch try to solve by itself the type and it assign a datatype to the new field. So it has found a numeric value inside the countCalls and it defines as `long` datatype. Then later a new ingestion instance try to index a document with the field `countCalls` but inside there isn't a numeric value, but a string. Elastic try to merge this value in the field but it can't because now the field is defined as long datatype. The fastest way to solve this problem is to define the field in the mapping as `text` datatype. In this way the numeric value will be cast to text datatype. On the other hand you could not anymore do a `range` query on this field. So the question is, is useful to make a `range` query for this field?

Comment: I didn't set any mapping to that field si I thought it will set it automatically. I don't need to search or do range query for that field. 
So I need to define in mapping as a keyword? Or?

Comment: or text datatype. This will impact the query you could make against this field

Comment: @13Akaren see my comment

Comment: I set it  

`"countCalls": {
                "index": false,
                "type": "text"
            },`

Create new index with this mapping and still same error.

Comment: really!? try:"counterCalls": {
        "type": "text",
        "coerce": true ,index:false
      } https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html